# Return pmin or pmax of data.frame with multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to select the pmax/pmin of a data frame with multiple columns??

I want only the max or min returned, not the entire row.

```
max <- tail(df, n=1)
max
#                       v1     v2     v3     v4     v5     v6     v7     v8
#2014-10-03 17:35:00  58.91  45.81  33.06  70.76  36.39  45.53  33.52  34.36

pmax(max)
#                       v1     v2     v3     v4     v5     v6     v7     v8
#2014-10-03 17:35:00  58.91  45.81  33.06  70.76  36.39  45.53  33.52  34.36
```

For this row, I expect a return value of :

```
70.76
```

...as it is the maximum value across all the columns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `do.call` to call `pmax` to compare all the columns together for each row value, e.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=rep(3,5))

#  a b
#1 1 3
#2 2 3
#3 3 3
#4 4 3
#5 5 3

do.call(pmax,dat)
#[1] 3 3 3 4 5
```

When you call `pmax` on an entire data.frame directly, it only has one argument passed to the function and nothing to compare it to. So, it just returns the supplied argument as it must be the maximum. It works for non-numeric and numeric arguments, even though it may not make much sense:

```
pmax(7)
#[1] 7

pmax("a")
#[1] "a"

pmax(data.frame(1,2,3))
#  X1 X2 X3
#1  1  2  3
```

Using `do.call(pmax,...)` with a data.frame means you pass each column of the data.frame as a list of arguments to `pmax`:

```
do.call(pmax,dat)
```

is thus equivalent to:

```
pmax(dat$a, dat$b)
```

Comment: This does not work with NAs. How can I pass na.rm = TRUE to do.call?

Comment: @JASC - `do.call(pmax, c(dat, na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` way if you like

```r
df <- structure(list(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
                           "I", "J"), Y_1 = c(34, 29, 94, 53, 84, 53, 92, 41, 49, 32), Y_2 = c(43, 
                                                                                               26, 29, 64, 68, 88, 36, 86, 74, 15), Y_3 = c(62, 72, 69, 54, 
                                                                                                                                            80, 49, 51, 41, 46, 68), Y_4 = c(92, 45, 21, 27, 60, 32, 40, 
                                                                                                                                                                             40, 39, 89), Y_5 = c(28, 79, 34, 84, 58, 16, 69, 53, 78, 80), 
                     Y_6 = c(91, 55, 45, 70, 81, 19, 33, 90, 28, 82), Y_7 = c(95, 
                                                                              75, 11, 81, 12, 38, 53, 88, 74, 51), Y_8 = c(69, 99, 44, 
                                                                                                                           20, 53, 57, 79, 45, 21, 47), Y_9 = c(67, 44, 88, 75, 76, 
                                                                                                                                                                70, 18, 80, 32, 83), Y_10 = c(16, 80, 41, 47, 72, 47, 89, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              96, 23, 64)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"))
df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 11
#>    X       Y_1   Y_2   Y_3   Y_4   Y_5   Y_6   Y_7   Y_8   Y_9  Y_10
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A        34    43    62    92    28    91    95    69    67    16
#>  2 B        29    26    72    45    79    55    75    99    44    80
#>  3 C        94    29    69    21    34    45    11    44    88    41
#>  4 D        53    64    54    27    84    70    81    20    75    47
#>  5 E        84    68    80    60    58    81    12    53    76    72
#>  6 F        53    88    49    32    16    19    38    57    70    47
#>  7 G        92    36    51    40    69    33    53    79    18    89
#>  8 H        41    86    41    40    53    90    88    45    80    96
#>  9 I        49    74    46    39    78    28    74    21    32    23
#> 10 J        32    15    68    89    80    82    51    47    83    64

library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(max_val = max(c_across(where(is.numeric))))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 12
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    X       Y_1   Y_2   Y_3   Y_4   Y_5   Y_6   Y_7   Y_8   Y_9  Y_10 max_val
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 A        34    43    62    92    28    91    95    69    67    16      95
#>  2 B        29    26    72    45    79    55    75    99    44    80      99
#>  3 C        94    29    69    21    34    45    11    44    88    41      94
#>  4 D        53    64    54    27    84    70    81    20    75    47      84
#>  5 E        84    68    80    60    58    81    12    53    76    72      84
#>  6 F        53    88    49    32    16    19    38    57    70    47      88
#>  7 G        92    36    51    40    69    33    53    79    18    89      92
#>  8 H        41    86    41    40    53    90    88    45    80    96      96
#>  9 I        49    74    46    39    78    28    74    21    32    23      78
#> 10 J        32    15    68    89    80    82    51    47    83    64      89
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to AnilGovyl for the data!

Here is another `dplyr` option, using `rlang` and quasiquotation: learned here: [dplyr mutate rowwise max of range of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978458/dplyr-mutate-rowwise-max-of-range-of-columns/32978686) answer by Ben

First we get all columns to test and the we can use `!!!` and `rlang::syms` to compute the parallel max for every row of those columns:

`rlang::syms` takes a string input (the column names), and turns it into a symbol
`!!!` unquotes and splices its argument, here the column names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

df_cols <- df %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% names()

df %>% 
mutate(max_val=pmax(!!!rlang::syms(df_cols)))
```

Output:

```
   X       Y_1   Y_2   Y_3   Y_4   Y_5   Y_6   Y_7   Y_8   Y_9  Y_10 max_val
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A        34    43    62    92    28    91    95    69    67    16      95
 2 B        29    26    72    45    79    55    75    99    44    80      99
 3 C        94    29    69    21    34    45    11    44    88    41      94
 4 D        53    64    54    27    84    70    81    20    75    47      84
 5 E        84    68    80    60    58    81    12    53    76    72      84
 6 F        53    88    49    32    16    19    38    57    70    47      88
 7 G        92    36    51    40    69    33    53    79    18    89      92
 8 H        41    86    41    40    53    90    88    45    80    96      96
 9 I        49    74    46    39    78    28    74    21    32    23      78
10 J        32    15    68    89    80    82    51    47    83    64      89
```

Comment: You may also use `max.col` to get `colnames` where maximum value is

Comment: You can make this more concise by doing the select from the pipe

`df %>% mutate(max_val = pmax(!!!select(., where(is.numeric))))`