# get column name based on row values matching in DF in R

Tags: r

I have a table like below, would like to crate suggestions based on row value in R studio.

This is what I have -

| id | class1 | class2 | class3 | class4 | top1 | top2 | top3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.98 | 0.48 | 0.21 | 0.99 | 0.99 | 0.98 | 0.48 |
| B | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.41 | 0.11 | 0.41 | 0.31 | 0.22 |
| C | 0.70 | 0.81 | 0.61 | 0.21 | 0.81 | 0.70 | 0.61 |

I would like to have names of the column for top1 top2 top3 as well.

| id | class1 | class2 | class3 | class4 | top1 | top2 | top3 | top1name | top2name | top3name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.98 | 0.48 | 0.21 | 0.99 | 0.99 | 0.98 | 0.48 | class4 | class1 | class2 |
| B | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.41 | 0.11 | 0.41 | 0.31 | 0.22 | class3 | class2 | class1 |
| C | 0.70 | 0.81 | 0.61 | 0.21 | 0.81 | 0.70 | 0.61 | class2 | class1 | class3 |

Sample data:

I have a table like below, would like to crate suggestions based on row value in R studio.

This is what I have :

| id | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.98 | 0.48 | 0.21 | 0.97 | 0.47 | 0.20 | 0.19 |
| B | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.41 | 0.11 | 0.42 | 0.32 | 0.23 |
| C | 0.70 | 0.81 | 0.61 | 0.21 | 0.82 | 0.71 | 0.62 |

I would like to have names of the column for top1 top2 top3 as well.

| id | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | top1name | top2name | top3name | top4name | top5name | top6name | top7name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.98 | 0.48 | 0.21 | 0.97 | 0.47 | 0.20 |  | A | D | B | E | C | F |  |
| B | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.41 | 0.11 | 0.42 | 0.32 | 0.23 | E | C | F | B | G | A | D |
| C | 0.70 | 0.81 | 0.61 | 0.21 | 0.82 | 0.71 | 0.62 | E | B | F | A | G | C | D |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr mutate rowwise max of range of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978458/dplyr-mutate-rowwise-max-of-range-of-columns)

Comment: No, it does not. I want names of the column w.r.t top1 column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using `dplyr::rowwise` with a custom function to generate three new columns containing the number of top classes. Ties between values are captured and displayed in ascending order of class names.

```r
library(dplyr)

get_top3_classes <- function(d) {

  r <- rank(-unlist(d), ties.method = "last")
  out <- names(sort(r))[1:3] 
  out <- gsub("class", "", out) # to get column class index
  m <- matrix(out,
              ncol = 3,
              dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("top", 1:3, "class"))
              )
  as_tibble(m)
  
}

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(get_top3_classes(
            across(matches("class"))
            )
         ) %>% 
  glimpse # for printing

#> Rows: 3
#> Columns: 11
#> Rowwise: 
#> $ id        <chr> "A", "B", "C"
#> $ class1    <dbl> 0.98, 0.22, 0.70
#> $ class2    <dbl> 0.48, 0.31, 0.81
#> $ class3    <dbl> 0.21, 0.41, 0.61
#> $ class4    <dbl> 0.99, 0.11, 0.21
#> $ top1      <dbl> 0.99, 0.41, 0.81
#> $ top2      <dbl> 0.98, 0.31, 0.70
#> $ top3      <dbl> 0.48, 0.22, 0.61
#> $ top1class <chr> "4", "3", "2"
#> $ top2class <chr> "1", "2", "1"
#> $ top3class <chr> "2", "1", "3"

# data containing a tie in the first row
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  id = c("A", "B", "C"),
  class1 = c(0.98, 0.22, 0.7),
  class2 = c(0.48, 0.31, 0.81),
  class3 = c(0.21, 0.41, 0.61),
  class4 = c(0.99, 0.11, 0.21),
  top1 = c(0.99, 0.41, 0.81),
  top2 = c(0.98, 0.31, 0.7),
  top3 = c(0.48, 0.22, 0.61)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Update:

Here is a solution for the updated question:

```r
library(dplyr)

get_top3_classes <- function(d) {
  
  r <- rank(-unlist(d), ties.method = "last")
  out <- names(sort(r)) 
  out <- gsub("class", "", out) # to get column class index
  m <- matrix(out,
              ncol = length(out),
              dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("top", seq(length(out)), "names"))
  )
  as_tibble(m)
  
}

dat %>% 
  rowwise(id) %>% 
  mutate(get_top3_classes(
    cur_data()
  )
  ) %>% 
  glimpse # for printing

#> Rows: 3
#> Columns: 15
#> Rowwise: id
#> $ id        <chr> "A", "B", "C"
#> $ A         <dbl> 0.98, 0.22, 0.70
#> $ B         <dbl> 0.48, 0.31, 0.81
#> $ C         <dbl> 0.21, 0.41, 0.61
#> $ D         <dbl> 0.97, 0.11, 0.21
#> $ E         <dbl> 0.47, 0.42, 0.82
#> $ F         <dbl> 0.20, 0.32, 0.71
#> $ G         <dbl> 0.19, 0.23, 0.62
#> $ top1names <chr> "A", "E", "E"
#> $ top2names <chr> "D", "C", "B"
#> $ top3names <chr> "B", "F", "F"
#> $ top4names <chr> "E", "B", "A"
#> $ top5names <chr> "C", "G", "G"
#> $ top6names <chr> "F", "A", "C"
#> $ top7names <chr> "G", "D", "D"

# data 
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,   ~A,   ~B,   ~C,   ~D,   ~E,   ~F,   ~G,
  "A", 0.98, 0.48, 0.21, 0.97, 0.47,  0.2, 0.19,
  "B", 0.22, 0.31, 0.41, 0.11, 0.42, 0.32, 0.23,
  "C",  0.7, 0.81, 0.61, 0.21, 0.82, 0.71, 0.62
)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, 
Instead of {matches("class")} ,can I give column index ??

Comment: how do you want to deal with cases where you have the same value in more than one column?
-based on alphabetical order of column name

Comment: @rgambhava this makes this problem quite more difficult. I will work on it later.

Comment: @rgambhava: I updated my answer. I hope I understood you correctly in that you are only interested in the class index and not the full class names.

Comment: hi @TimTeaFan, as I am increasing the classes to class 5,6....7. its is not working
Could you please help?

Comment: @rgambhava: Did you adjust the `ncol` and the `dimnames` argument in the `matrix` call`? If you add some sample data to your question it should be easy to help you adusting the function.

Comment: Yes, I did. I am adding some sample data.
Function i used:`
get_top3_classes <- function(d) {

  r <- rank(-unlist(d), ties.method = "last")
  out <- names(sort(r))[1:7] 
  out <- gsub("class", "", out) # to get column class index
  m <- matrix(out,
              ncol = 7,
              dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("top", 1:7, "class"))
              )
  as_tibble(m)
  
}`

Comment: @rgambhava: I update my answer. Please upvote if it solves your problem.

Comment: It is working. But it showing column names for null values as well. Is is possible to ignore null values present in  column "A"..to .. "G"?

Comment: ACCNT_ID A B C D E F G top1names top2names top3names top4names top5names top6names top7names
1 289739509 89.86 NA NA 50.82 NA 5.52 NA A D F B C E G
2 698811605 79.55 NA NA 32.02 19.85 2.65 23.16 A D G E F B C

Comment: hi @TimTeaFan, I figured it out. Thank you so much for the help.