# Select specific/all columns in rowwise

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following table:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 6 | 3 |

My goal is to find the max value per each row, and then find how many times it was repeated in the same row.

The resulting table should look like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | max_val | repetition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | 6 | 3 | 6 | 2 |

Now to achieve this, I am doing the following for Max:

```
df%>% rowwise%>%
mutate(max=max(col1:col4))
```

However, I am struggling to find the repetition. My idea is to use this pseudo code in mutate:
sum( "select current row entirely or only for some columns"==max). But I don't know how to select entire row or only some columns of it and use its content to do the check, i.e.: is it equal to the max. How can we do this in dplyr?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr mutate rowwise max of range of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978458/dplyr-mutate-rowwise-max-of-range-of-columns)

Comment: It only partially answers the question as my goal here is not actually to calculate the max but to find a way to select all/specific columns in rowwise operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max_val = max(across(everything())),
         repetition = sum(across(col1:col4) == max_val))

# A tibble: 2 × 6
# Rowwise: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4 max_val repetition
  <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>      <int>
1     1     2     1     4       4          1
2     5     6     6     3       6          2
```

An R base approach:

```
df$max_val <- apply(df,1,max)
df$repetition <- rowSums(df[, 1:4] == df[, 5])
```

Comment: So the answer is to use: across(everything()) to select all current row column values, and across(colname:colname) for specific selection. Thnaks!

Comment: @GitZine you may want to accept one of the answers provided for indicating your problem is solved.

Comment: Ah, I thought I already accepted your answer, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

For other (non-tidyverse) readers, a base R approach could be:

```
df$max_val  <- apply(df, 1, max)
df$repetition <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x[1:4] == x[5]))
```

Output:

```
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 max_val repetition
# 1    1    2    1    4       4          1
# 2    5    6    6    3       6          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Although dplyr has added many tools for working across rows of data, it remains, in my mind at least, much easier to adhere to tidy principles and always convert the data to "long" format for these kinds of operations.

Thus, here is a [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) approach:

```
df %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    mutate(max_val = max(value), repetitions = sum(value == max(value))) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(row, max_val, repetitions)) %>%
    select(col1:col4, max_val, repetitions)
```

The last `select()` is just to get the columns in the order you want.